# Weekly Data Sql Query Thursday to Wednesday

Tags: sql, sql-server

By using below the link I am trying to make a weekly query. My week starts on Thursday and lasts to Wednesday which I change correctly but the sum of (Field1) is not out coming correctly. What I am doing wrong?

[Query for weekly report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280778/query-for-weekly-report)

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000104', START_DATETIME), '19000104') AS EveryThrusday,
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000104', START_DATETIME)+1, '19000104') - 1 AS EveryWednesday,
    SUM(Field1)
FROM 
    Table1
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000104', START_DATETIME), '19000104'),  
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000104', START_DATETIME)+1, '19000104')-1
ORDER BY
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000104', START_DATETIME), '19000104'),  
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000104', START_DATETIME)+1, '19000104')-1
```

`Table 1`:

```
Date        field1
1-May-14    102948.66
2-May-14    102927.21
3-May-14    102925.89
4-May-14    102427.55
5-May-14    101551.95
6-May-14    102952.12
7-May-14    102947.53
```

Total = **718680.93**

`Table 2`:

```
Start date  End date    field1
1-May-14    7-May-14    719793.72
```

In the first table I am retrieving the data on per day basis from Thursday 1 May to 7th May. The sum of those days is 718680.93

But if I run the weekly query see values is different in field1 table 2

Comment: What if you just say `group by field1`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i need to add more fields ... like near to 10. will it works for me?

Comment: Can you describe what you want this query to do?  What is the layout of Table1?  My first inclination would be to select your DATEADD values in a subquery/inline view and then do the group by.

Comment: show your table schema

Comment: Please see i add the table layout

Answer (score 1):

You could easily see why the sum differs from the correct value by looking at the result of `DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000104', START_DATETIME), '19000104')` for every date in your range. The following query:

```
SELECT
  START_DATETIME,
  Thursday = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000104', START_DATETIME), '19000104')
FROM dbo.Table1;
```

would give you results like these:

```
START_DATETIME  Thursday
--------------  ----------
2014-05-01      2014-05-01
2014-05-02      2014-05-01
2014-05-03      2014-05-01
2014-05-04      2014-05-08
2014-05-05      2014-05-08
2014-05-06      2014-05-08
2014-05-07      2014-05-08
```

As you can see, your expression does not return identical results for all the dates within the same week that starts on Thursday. As a result, your query groups different dates, which, in turn, is why you get the incorrect results.

Please note that the expression would return same inconsistent dates *regardless of the `DATEFIRST` setting*, because `DATEDIFF` [does not respect that setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle) and always calculates the result as if `DATEFIRST` was set to 7.

To work around this issue, you could replace the `DATEDIFF(WEEK)` by `DATEDIFF(DAY) / 7`:

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000104', START_DATETIME) / 7, '19000104')
```

Since both operands would be integer, SQL Server would perform integral division and its result, therefore, would be a whole (and correct in this case) number of weeks.

Alternatively, you could calculate the beginning of the week by subtracting the week day number from the date:

```
DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, START_DATETIME), START_DATETIME)
```

Similarly, the end of the week would be using `7 - DATEPART(...)`. The above assumes that `DATEFIRST` is set to 4 (i.e. Thursday). If it is different in your environment, you would need to adjust the second argument of `DATEADD` accordingly.

Comment: Hello Guru Andriy M,  Thank you very much your solution really works for me many thanks for your kindness.